# Does it make sense to watch(self) in akka?

Tags: akka

As far as I understand, `context.watch` simply delivers `actor.Terminated` message to watcher. I wanted it to be the last message that actor receives. Yet, I see that it is never delivered. I guess it can be because it is terminated and does not process messages anymore. As part of the answer you may tell what is expected behaviour. You can also tell what is the way to handle the stop condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you've already answered your own question: watching `self` will not result in that actor receiving a `Terminated` message for itself.  The real question is *why* you need that message.  If you just need to clean up resources, override `postStop` and put that logic there.

`postStop` is guaranteed to be executed *after* messages have stopped being enqueued in that actor's mailbox so you can be sure nothing will come after it.